# UX StackExchange logo is hard to see in the SE profile pages (accounts tab)

Tags: feature-request, design

The logo is really low contrast compared to elsewhere on UX, where the monochrome logo is used or the darker blue of the favicon.

> [image: low contrast UX logo]

[See here](http://stackexchange.com/users/41278?tab=accounts) for a live example.

Comment: The U definately needs to be darker. You can't see the star at all and the u is hard to see itself.

Comment: Agreed, it looks pretty bad.  Do we have freedom to change the background colour or only the U and X?

Comment: yeah - it should really be same blue as in the favicon or the drop down list of all sites from the top se navbar

Comment: same issue on the top level [SE sites listing](http://stackexchange.com/sites):

Comment: I've never even seen that blue on this site, it should be the same as the favicon. @JohnGB I'm not sure what you'd want to change the background color too, but almost all the other site icons have the same white background or the "sketchy" backdrop for beta sites.

Comment: A dark border to separate the white background from the negative space on the icon would be a good touch, and would make the icon pop.  Of course, it would be visually inconsistent, but it would also draw attention to the UX/UI Q&A ... which really does need more (general) attention.