# UX Stack Exchange logo is extremely hard to see in the mobile version header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, logo, mobile

This is a similar issue to [the one affecting the SE profile pages](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/ux-stackexchange-logo-is-hard-to-see-in-the-se-profile-pages-accounts-tab), but affects the mobile version of the website.

[image: A screenshot of the problem taken by changing the Safari user agent string to mimic the iPhone]

This fails [the WCAG contrast checking algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20070517/Overview.html#G18), which recommends that the contrast ratio be at least 5:1. According to the OS X version of the Colour Contrast Analyser tool, the ratio according to the algorithm is currently 1.1:1:

> Foreground: #173B5B - Background: #313C57
>
> The contrast ratio is: 1.1:1
>
> Text failed at level AA Text failed at level AAA Large text failed at
>   level AA Large text failed at level AAA
>
> 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum):  Text (and images of text) have a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1, except if the text is pure decoration. 
>   Larger scale text (at least 18 point or 14 point bold) or images of
>   text can have a contrast ratio of 3:1. (Level AA)
>
> 1.4.6 Contrast (Enhanced): Text (and images of text) have a contrast ratio of at least 7:1, except if the text is pure decoration.  Larger
>   scale text (at least 18 point or 14 point bold) or images of text can
>   have a contrast ratio of 4.5:1. (Level AAA)
>
> colour difference:31 / brightness difference:8
>
> The difference in brightness between the two colours is not
>   sufficient. The threshold is 125, and the result of the foreground and
>   background colours is 8.
>
> The difference in colour between the two colours is not sufficient.
>   The threshold is 500, and the result of the foreground and background
>   colours is 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 48x48 site icon was meant for desktop use(where the bg is white). It obviously didn't work well for the UX site on mobile. So I updated the color scheme. so the contrast ratio is about 1.75:1.

[image]

The update will be in the next production build.

Comment: That's a vast improvement, but still very low-contrast relative to the WCAG recommendation.

Comment: Is there a reason we wouldn't use the all-white version of the logo as on the desktop version header?

Comment: @jin what do you think of this variation of the logo: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/improved-ux-logo