# UX icon in Stack Exchange All Sites is hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Was looking for the UX bubble on [Stack Exchange's All Sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) page. Couldn't find the icon. Well, here's your problem:

[image]

It's even more invisible in context.It's like [UX StackExchange logo is hard to see in the SE profile pages (accounts tab)](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/ux-stackexchange-logo-is-hard-to-see-in-the-se-profile-pages-accounts-tab) but way worse.

Could we get a tweak to make that U a bit more visible?

Comment: Who has the asset?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye Stack Exchange, it's hosted at http://cdn.sstatic.net/ux/img/icon-48.png

Comment: Does anyone have a PSD or editable vector, though?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye presumably [Jin](https://twitter.com/jzy); otherwise I'm not sure where they'd have higher-resulution/vector copies

Comment: Researched a bit of Jin's work on SE (means: read his blog), currently I try to find out, what was the design intent with these colors, they look like the global SE colors, but hexa-wise a bit different.. I'm nearly sure he has a palette somewhere. Is he too busy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. I have no idea why I picked the colors I did... it will be in the next production build. (you may need to refresh browser to see the change).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

[image: UX site logo]

I guess @Jin tried to use the default SE colors when designing UX.SE, all I did was basically grabbed the current logo, grabbed the bg color of the header, then the bg color of the SE bar on top, and used these colors, this way trying to be faithful to the original palette.

The cutting is terrible, but we're full of visual designers on this site, someone surely could do it properly if they like the idea. Hey, I'm an engineer, I can't do pretty things! :)

Comment: +1, this is basically exactly what appears in http://cdn.sstatic.net/ux/img/newsletter-ad.png and the favicon, and until I saw this post, I thought this *was* the "official" UX.SE logo.